# Ich weiß, dass(,) wenn meine Mutter das sieht, dann hat sie Ärger

Tags: comma

Ist es wahr, dass das erste Komma obligatorisch ist, aber das zweite inkorrekt wäre, wenn es da gesetzt werden würde?

1. Ich weiß, dass(,) wenn meine Mutter das sieht, sie Ärger hat.
2. Ich weiß, dass(,) wenn meine Mutter das sieht, dann sie Ärger hat.

Comment: Der zweite Satz ist kein korrektes Deutsch. Wer behauptet (bzw. warum glaubst Du), dass das geklammerte Komma im ersten Satz fakultativ ist?

Comment: Ich halte Variante 1 für bestenfalls in mündlicher Form akzeptabel.  Normal wäre: *dass meine Mutter Ärger hat (bekommt ?), wenn sie das sieht*.

Comment: @guidot, Einspruch, denn dann hätte ja die Mutter Ärger. In der ursprünglichen Form hat jemand anders den Ärger, der dadurch entsteht, dass die Mutter das sieht.

Comment: Auch hier der Hinweis, dass 1. eine theoretische und in gesprochener Sprache kaum vorkommende Formulierung ist. (2. ist falsch) Gebräuchlicher wäre es zu sagen "ich weiß dass meine Mutter Ärger hat/bekommt, wenn sie das sieht". Die Formulierung klingt aber wirklich ungewöhnlich. Sie bedeutet, wenn die Mutter das sieht, ärgert sich eine anderen Person über die Mutter. Die Mutter bekommt also Ärger. Das kann zwar sein, wenn die Mutter etwas nicht sehen darf und es trotzdem sieht, aber vielleicht ist auch etwas anderes gemeint?

Comment: Formulierungen 1. und 2. sind unbhängig vom Komma misslungen. Ich vermute, dass, wenn ich das richtig verstehe, Folgendes gemeint ist: "Wenn meine Mutter das sieht, wird sie ärgerlich".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Richtig ist der erste Satz mit allen drei Kommas:

> Ich weiß, dass, wenn meine Mutter das sieht, sie Ärger hat.

Der Grund für die Kommasetzung liegt in der Struktur des Satzes:

> HS, NS<sub>1</sub>, NS<sub>2</sub>, NS<sub>1</sub>.

- HS: Ich weiß
- NS<sub>1</sub>: dass sie Ärger hat
- NS<sub>2</sub>: wenn meine Mutter das sieht

Da es sich bei NS<sub>2</sub> um einen *eingeschobenen* Nebensatz handelt, muss er gemäß [§ 74 des amtlichen Regelwerks](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par74) mit *paarigem Komma* abgetrennt werden.

---

**Edit**:

In der ersten Version dieser Antwort hatte ich geschrieben, dass der zweite Satz für mich ungrammatisch klingt, da die Wortreihenfolge im ersten Nebensatz („dass dann sie Ärger hat“) nicht stimmen würde und es eher „dass sie dann Ärger hat“ heißen müsste. Letzteres wäre zwar die [*unmarkierte*](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/820) Wortreihenfolge, aber auch die Reihenfolge im Original ist grammatikalisch richtig. Sie ist jedoch [*markiert*](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/820), das heißt, sie weicht von der Standardreihenfolge ab, und führt zu einer starken Betonung des Wortes *sie*. Auch hier gelten die Kommaregeln wie oben:

> Ich weiß, dass, wenn meine Mutter das sieht, dann *sie* Ärger hat (und nicht etwa ich).